# Angular2 - require some clarity

Tags: angular

I have a doubt with current beta version of the `angular2` any please help me to understand or show me a correct technical document?

1) here is my `app.component` where I am only exporting `AppComponent`. But How my `@Component` getting name here? how this is connected?

```ts
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';


interface Hero {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2> //but how i am getting name here?
        <div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
        <div>
            <label>name: </label>
            <div><input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name"></div>
        </div>
    `
})



export class AppComponent {

    public title = "Tour of Heros";
    public hero : Hero = {

        id :1,
        name: 'Windstorm'

    } 

}
```

2. here is my `boot.ts` it only getting `AppComponent` alone. not `@Component` but still how the `@component` template available in the html? how `boot.ts` getting my `template` from `AppComponent`.

```ts
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

any one clarify me. I am  very new to `angular2`.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your questions are mostly answered in the [quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) page:

> A class becomes an Angular component when we give it metadata. We define a component's metadata with the Angular Component function.
>
> In TypeScript we apply that function to the class as a decorator by prefixing it with the @ symbol and invoking it just above the component class.
> @Component tells Angular that this class is an Angular component.
>
> When Angular calls the bootstrap function in boot.ts, it reads the AppComponent metadata, finds the my-app selector, locates an element tag named my-app, and loads our application between those tags.

Also, have a look at the JavaScript file that is generated by the TypeScript compiler: `app.component.js`.  You'll see that the template gets added to the `AppComponent` function that is generated.